# Unable to Upload Files

Tags: errors, uploads

So, I have Wordpress installed on a GoDaddy server, and I am getting an error saying:

> Unable to create directory uploads/2016/03. Is its parent directory writable by the server?

The folder exists on the server already, and the entire `wp-content/` folder and it's sub-folders have `775` permissions. What is the issue for this? I am at such a loss right now...

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the issue.

Under `Settings > Media` there is a text field saying where to upload the files to, and it was the wrong directory. I just changed it to the right one and it worked.